# Pagination on filtered rows — Resetting original data set — jQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

This is a problem I had with jQuery Datatables that I really don't know why it is happening in the first place!

I have multiple select elements which all filters the original data set. I do the filtering logic on the select change event.

This my Datatables init (using state saving, from the documentation) :

```
var table = $('#orders-listing').DataTable({
   bStateSave: true, 
   bFilter:true, 
   paging: true, 
   bPaginate:true,
   language: { url: /* Language File URL */ },
   fnStateSave: function(oSettings, oData){
     localStorage.setItem('DataTables_'+window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(oData));
   },
   fnStateLoad: function(oSettings){
     return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DataTables_'+window.location.pathname));
   }
});
```

And this is my filtering logic on the select change event:

```
$('.filter-select').on('change', function() {

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.afnFiltering.push(
     function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
          // Some logic, return a boolean, wether we keep the row being processed or not.
     }
  );

  table.draw(); 
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.afnFiltering.pop();
});
```

Now, the filtering works fine. The rows, pagination links, everything changes accordingly.
But, once I click on the 2nd link on the pagination links, the original dataset returns.

*Example*: I had 200 rows in the first place, after filtering, it was reduced to 150 (So 50 rows were filtered, and removed from the original dataset), then once I click on the second link on the pagination, the original dataset returns, with the first 200 rows.

What am I missing here ? What is causing the original dataset to return when paginating ?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're doing `$.fn.dataTable.ext.afnFiltering.pop();` immediately after drawing the table with `draw()` which removes your custom filter and it will no longer be applied if table is sorted, page is changed, etc. Try adding `$.fn.dataTable.ext.afnFiltering.pop();` before `$.fn.dataTable.ext.afnFiltering.push()` to remove previous custom filter only on filter change.

Comment: I didn't think about that, really! Thanks a lot man! It works fine now!

Comment: Also I wouldn't recommend mixing options with old and new naming conventions, `paging` and `bPaginate` is the same thing, remove `bPaginate` for code clarity. See [conversion guide](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) for proper option names.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing `$.fn.dataTable.ext.afnFiltering.pop()` immediately after drawing the table with `draw()` which removes your custom filter and it will no longer be applied if table is sorted, page is changed, etc.

Try adding `$.fn.dataTable.ext.afnFiltering.pop()` before `$.fn.dataTable.ext.afnFiltering.push()` to remove previous custom filter only on filter change but before adding a new filter.